# Ignoring special symbols in xsl:sort

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a problem.
There are some items, contains terms such a:

```
<term>Emploee's earnings...</term>
<term>Emploee Withholdings...</term>
<term>...value of an...</term>
<term>...value of a...</term>
```

As per logic the "an" article shold be after "a". Also, "Emploee's" should be after "Emploee".
The question is how to do it with the xsl:sort?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I do not really see what your problem is.
Using xsl:sort within an :apply-templates (or for-each) should sort as desired.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="term" >
    <xsl:sort select="text()"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

To adapted the language specific handling you can add a "lang" attribute.
If you like to ignore some character you can use `translate()`.
Example to ignore the apostrophe (not necessary here):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="term" >
    <xsl:sort select='translate(text(),"&apos;", "")'/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: This answer is partially solve the problem, but the plural form of the words goes first. For example "Times interest earned ratio" goes before "Time value of money" in the sorting output.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you'll find that true natural-language sorting, at the level where for example titles of books are sorted ignoring an initial "The" or "A", is beyond the capability of most XSLT engines - and for that matter, most general-purpose sorting utilities. This is because it's very application-dependent. Check, for example, how your phone book sorts "McMillan" and "Macmillan".

If you can write a function that normalizes the data (e.g. by removing the unwanted leading definite or indefinite article), then in XSLT 2.0 you can invoke this function in the select attribute of xsl:sort to normalize the key prior to sorting.

Comment: I'm not going to attempt a more precise solution than the general outline above unless you can provide a precise specification.